# MVC form does not submit Angular form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, forms

My MVC form does not submit back to the controller if I remove the default Html.BeginForm and replace with any other form. What am I missing?

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

and replace for this Angular form

```
@model ReNtZBookings.Models.tblBooking
<div id="example" class="container">
<form name="form1" ng-app novalidate>
```

Comment: Are you using ng-form? How is your routing configured?

Comment: it is a templated MVC form that I a attempting to change into Angular as there is lot of data on the form that I think would be handled better. routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "bookMe", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to mix the two and I don't think that's possible. You would need to do something like this:

```
   <div data-ng-app="app">
    <form name="form1" ng-form="submitForm()" ng-controller="yourController" novalidate>
       <input type="text" ng-model="yourmodel.name" />
       <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
   </div>
```

then in your angularjs controller, you would need to add the submitForm() method

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("yourController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.yourmodel = {};
   $scope.submitForm = function() {
      $http.post({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        data: $scope.yourmodel,
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('success');
      }
   }
}]);
```